# Python Datetime doing not working properly

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to def a function which will return the current quarter of the year in a string.

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime(2022,1,1)
        
month = date.month
        
year = date.year
    
if month ==1 or 2 or 3:
    quarter = 'Q1'
if month ==4 or 5 or 6:
    quarter = 'Q2'        
if month ==7 or 8 or 9:
    quarter = 'Q3'
if month ==10 or 11 or 12:
    quarter = 'Q4'          
    
lookup = quarter +str(year)
    
print(lookup)
```

when I run this function I get Q42022. Am I missing something in the if/or statements.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly specify

```
if month==1 or month==2 or month==3:
```

You could also check inclusion

```
if month in (1, 2, 3):
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
if month in {1, 2, 3}:
# and so on
```